# python recursive function doesn't return anything at all

Tags: python, list, function, recursion, return

i wrote the following function:

```
def splitter(input, inc=0):
    if inc == len(regex):
        print "return point reached"
        return input
    print inc, input
    output = []
    if type(input) is list:
        for i in input:
            o = re.split(regex[inc],i)
            if not o[0] == i:
                for x in o:
                    output.append(x)
            else:
                output.append(i)
    else:
        o = re.split(regex[inc],input)
        if not o[0] == input:
            for x in o:
                output.append(x)
        else:
            output.append(input)
    inc+=1
    splitter(output, inc)
```

regex is defined as:

```
regex = [' & ',' / ',' \+ ',' and ',' und ',' ft\. ',' feat\. ']
```

input is some string like

```
"Benga und Welsh ft. Warrior Queen and Skream feat. Benny Ill"
```

the goal is to split the string at every point specified by an entry in regex.
the output printed by the line `print inc, input` does the expected thing (it gives `['Benga', 'Welsh', 'Warrior Queen', 'Skream feat. Benny Ill']` for input), even the line stating `print "return point reached"` is being executed, but the function desn't seem to return anything at all.
is it important to know that i call the function from the django manage.py-shell?

thanks for any helping ideas!
r

Comment: Please fix the format/indent. Otherwise, it's hard to see where the function definition ends.

Comment: you forgot to `return splitter(output,inc)` on last line

Comment: why not go through with debugger?

Comment: Your indentation needs some work, as what is posted now is not even valid. The only place where your function returns anything is under `if inc == length(gex)`. I suspect you intended to `return output` or something at the end of the function, but I'm not sure if your last two lines are intended to be part of the function, or outside it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `return` at the very last line of your function.  Here is an example of the working code, with indenting fixed:

```
import re

regex = [' & ',' / ',' \+ ',' and ',' und ',' ft\. ',' feat\. ']

def splitter(input, inc=0):
    if inc == len(regex):
        print "return point reached"
        return input
    print inc, input
    output = []
    if type(input) is list:
        for i in input:
            o = re.split(regex[inc], i)
            if not o[0] == i:
                for x in o:
                    output.append(x)
            else:
                output.append(i)
    else:
        o = re.split(regex[inc], input)
        if not o[0] == input:
            for x in o:
                output.append(x)
        else:
            output.append(input)
    inc += 1

    # I added the return statement here:
    return splitter(output, inc)

print(splitter("Benga und Welsh ft. Warrior Queen and Skream feat. Benny Ill"))
```

The output:

```
0 Benga und Welsh ft. Warrior Queen and Skream feat. Benny Ill
1 ['Benga und Welsh ft. Warrior Queen and Skream feat. Benny Ill']
2 ['Benga und Welsh ft. Warrior Queen and Skream feat. Benny Ill']
3 ['Benga und Welsh ft. Warrior Queen and Skream feat. Benny Ill']
4 ['Benga und Welsh ft. Warrior Queen', 'Skream feat. Benny Ill']
5 ['Benga', 'Welsh ft. Warrior Queen', 'Skream feat. Benny Ill']
6 ['Benga', 'Welsh', 'Warrior Queen', 'Skream feat. Benny Ill']
return point reached
['Benga', 'Welsh', 'Warrior Queen', 'Skream', 'Benny Ill']
```